# Asking for password prompt in Capistrano 3

Tags: capistrano

What is the equivalent API of `Capistrano::CLI#password_prompt` in Capistrano 3? It seems to me this DSL has been removed. For the time being, I ended up using `highline` gem.

Comment: As of 2015 Capistrano ships with `highline` gem and supports `echo: false` option for `ask` method. Related answer — http://stackoverflow.com/a/31615306/535406

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was removed as Cap is an *automation tool*, for special use cases like your own Highline is Perfect. Cap3 does include an "#ask" method (see the docs) which is probably suitable for password input, but is used by default for asking which branch do deploy.