# Capistrano 3.0 — How securely prompt for password now?

Tags: ruby, deployment, capistrano, capistrano3

Prior to `3.0` there was a way to do that:

```
# ...
set :mysql_password, proc { Capistrano::CLI.password_prompt "Gimme remote database server password. Don't worry, I won't tell anyone: " }
# ...

namespace :db do
  desc 'Dump remote database'
  task :dump do
    run "mysqldump -u #{mysql_user} -p #{mysql_database} > ~/#{mysql_database}.sql" do |channel, stream, data|
      if data =~ /^Enter password:/
        channel.send_data "#{mysql_password}\n"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

It prompts for password, doesn't show it as you type and leaves no traces of it in the logs and the output.

Now, as of `3.0` the only way I have found:

```
# ...

namespace :db do
  desc 'Dump remote database'
  task :dump do
    ask :mysql_password, nil
    on roles(:db) do
      execute "mysqldump -u#{fetch :mysql_user} -p#{fetch :mysql_password} #{fetch :mysql_database} > ~/#{fetch :mysql_database}.sql"
    end
  end
end
```

It does the job but reveals password everywhere.

Have anyone found a secure way for password prompting in `3.0`? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# Capistrano >= 3.3.3 supports `echo: false`
ask :password, 'default', echo: false
server 'server.domain.com', user: 'ssh_user_name', port: 22, password: fetch(:password), roles: %w{web app db}
```

— [faq@capistranorb.com](http://capistranorb.com/documentation/faq/how-can-i-get-capistrano-to-prompt-for-a-password/)
— [@mattbrictson, capistrano/capistrano](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/commit/4aebffe7188f08ab5d6740c176d9311397ab7887)

Answer (score 2):

Currently, [no](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/issues/878), might be on the next minor version (3.2):

> It would be helpful if `ask()` had an option to not echo input, similar
>   to the previous `Capistrano::CLI.password_prompt`

...

> Either way, it'll be a 3.2 thing.